# expand/collapse 2/3 of the table using jquery when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I am trying to expand and collapse 2/3 of the table rows when clicked on the footer.

```
 <table class="planTable"> 
    <tbody> 

        <tr> 
            <th>Plan</th> 
        </tr> 

        <tr class="cartItemGroup"> 
            <td > 
            10 
            GB 
            </td> 
        </tr> 

        <tr class="cartItemGroup">
            <td > 
            300 
            MB 
            </td> 
        </tr> 

        <tr class="cartItemGroup"> 
            <td > 
            1 
            GB 
            </td> 
        </tr> 

        <tr class="cartItemGroup"> 

            <td > 
            3 
            GB 
            </td> 
        </tr> 

        <tr class="cartItemGroup"> 
            <td > 
            6 
            GB 
            </td> 
        </tr> 

        <tr class="cartItemGroup">
            <td > 
            15 
            GB 
            </td> 
        </tr> 

        <tr class="cartItemGroup"> 
            <td > 
            20 
            GB 
            </td> 
        </tr> 

        <tr class="cartItemGroup">
            <td > 
            30 
            GB 
            </td>
        </tr> 

        <tr class="cartItemGroup"> 
            <td > 
            40 
            GB 
            </td> 
        </tr> 

        <tr class="cartItemGroup"> 
            <td > 
            50 
            GB 
            </td> 
        </tr> 

    </tbody> 
    <tfoot>
        <tr> 
            <td>  
                <a class="toggle planSection dBlock more-less collapseImg" href="javascript:void(0)"> 
                    <div> 
                        <font class="mrcLabel">Show top 3</font> 
                    </div> 
                </a> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

the footer contains the text that triggers the event with an anchor tag

It should be collapsed by default with "show all plans" as text
&
when expanded the text should automatically change to "show top 3"
and the text should remain in the bottom

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0exw99c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full disclosure this solution uses jQuery, but since you tagged with jQuery i figured it would be ok.

I slightly changed the markup to align with your default case to avoid content flashes while the JavaScript loads.

```
$(function () {
    var expandText = 'Show all plans',
        closeText  = 'Show top 3',
        isOpen = false,
        rowsToShowWhenCollapsed = 3,
        $rows = $('.cartItemGroup'),
        $triggerLink = $('.toggle');

    $triggerLink.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (isOpen) {
            closeRows();
            isOpen = false;
        } else {
            openRows();  
            isOpen = true;
        }
    }); 

    function closeRows () {
       var rowArray = $rows.toArray();

        $rows.hide();

        for (var i = 0; i < rowsToShowWhenCollapsed; i++) {
            $(rowArray[i]).show();
        }

        $triggerLink.find('span').text(expandText);
    }

    function openRows () {
        $rows.show();
        $triggerLink.find('span').text(closeText);
    }

    closeRows();
});
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xodjywd/1) to see it the code in action.

Comment: yes. this is what i was looking for. but something much simpler. by using id on the rows and triggering it using href in the <a> tag. with bootstrap

Comment: Don't really follow you. You can only point an anchor at 1 id. I'd say this solution is pretty simple...

Comment: when i try this code only with the table its working (http://jsfiddle.net/srrxyhhc/) but when i try to run it on the whole page through console after changing $ to jquery its not working(something is interfering with it).

Comment: after messing with console for some time i found that when a script contains  "jQuery(document).ready" runs on the page, the above script is not working. is there a workaround?

Comment: when i removed the .on() and directly gave it to the click it worked.  jQuery('.more-less').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if (isOpen) {
            closeRows();
            isOpen = false;
        } else {
            openRows();  
            isOpen = true;
        }
    });